# Java Files.copy() not copying files

Tags: java

I've made this method that copies files from one absolute path (input directory) to another absolute path (output directory).

It doesn't give me any error, however no files are copied to the output folder.

Why would this be?

```
public static boolean copyFiles(String input, String output)
{
    File source = new File(input);
    File dest = new File(output);
    try {
        Files.copy(Paths.get(input), Paths.get(output), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are input and output directories? `Files.copy` would copy that directory (`mkdir`), but not the files in it. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html

Comment: Yeah they are directories! Didn't know that! Will take a look

Comment: For me it works fine for files. :P

Comment: @reegnz Strange.. For me it didn't copy any files inside the directory (considering input & output are both directories).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @zapl said, Files.copy() only copies the directory.

I found the solution, by importing the Apache commons.io library.

```
org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(new File(input), new File(output));
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, the Files are copied, just that it is not shown in the project explorer (in Eclipse) so just refresh it will do.